# Java: Placing a Header in MS Word Document

Tags: java, ms-word, header

We are converting a C++ project to Java where we generate reports in ".doc" extension. The problem is we don't use any third party library to generate MS Word document, rather a file with .doc extension. Everything works fine except that we can't seem to find a way to add a Header at the beginning of every page. Using line numbers is not an option. Any other way it can be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library might be of some help.

It has facilities to read and modify Microsoft proprietary file formats like MS-Word .doc and MS-Excel .xls